# How to associate a Team Drive Apps Script with a GCP project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-shared-drive

I have :

- an apps script attached to a google doc hosted on my Drive.
- a GCP project
- a team drive

I need to deploy the apps script as an API executable. To do this, the app script needs to be attached to a GCP project so in the apps script I went to Resources > Cloud Platform project, typed in my GCP project number in the "Change Project" field, clicked changed project and everything worked perfectly.

What I am trying to do now is the exact same thing but with the google doc and attached script in my Team Drive instead of in my drive. If I move it to the team drive, when I try to set up the GCP project in apps script in the same way that above, I got the following error message:

> Project doesn't exist or you need edit access to it.

I guess it’s because when I move my file to the team drive I’m not the owner of it anymore so I can’t access the GCP project. But then how do I modify permissions to manage to do this ? I thought about adding a user to the GCP IAM with the good rights but is there a specific user for a team drive ?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't create a new project in a shared drive and convert it to a Cloud Managed Project.

The only way I could do it was to create a new project on my account, in My Drive, and convert that to a Cloud Managed Project, THEN move it to the shared drive. (Once it is in a shared drive, you can't MOVE it back out.) However, if it is a Cloud Managed Project, you can add more scopes to the project after it is in the shared drive. - Once this new project is setup, then copy over your code for your old copy, and point all links to the new one.